# Count percentage of observations that switch value

Tags: r, dplyr, count, percentage

I have a dataset that has two columns. One column indicates the group and each group has only two rows. The second column represents the category. Now I would like to count the percentage of each group not having the same category. So in row 1 and 2, the Category is not the same while in row 3 and 4 it is the same. In the provided data, I would get a percentage of 66.66% as four times the Category changes while it stays the same for two groups.

This is my data:

```
structure(list(Group = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", 
"E", "E", "F", "F"), Category = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

I have tried the following so far:

```
Data <- Data %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  count(n())
```

But I don't now how to write the code in the last line to get my desired percentage. Could someone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `base` solution with `tapply()`:

```r
mean(with(df, tapply(Category, Group, \(x) length(unique(x)))) > 1)

# [1] 0.6666667
```

With `dplyr`, you could use `n_distinct()` to count the number of unique values.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(N = n_distinct(Category)) %>%
  summarise(Percent = mean(N > 1))

# # A tibble: 1 × 1
#   Percent
#     <dbl>
# 1   0.667
```

Comment: Thank you very much Darren Tsai!! This helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To show it for both classes, you can use the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(unique = as.numeric(n_distinct(Category) == 1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  summarise(Percent = prop.table(table(unique)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 1
  Percent  
  <table>  
1 0.6666667
2 0.3333333
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base R

```
counts <- table(df)
prop.table(table(rowSums(counts != 0)))
```

-output

```
        1         2 
0.3333333 0.6666667
```